# AllowMultipleValues in taxonomy field in CSOM Javascript

Tags: javascript, csom, jsom, taxonomy

I am trying to create a taxonomy column within JSOM , I am nearly there but I have set the type to :

```
var fieldSchema = `<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" 
                           Name="SessionTopics" 
                           DisplayName="Session Topics"
                         Required="TRUE" 
                        Group="Limited Document Library" />`;
```

and the allow multiple values is still not ticked within the column settings.

I have seen that there is a `AllowMultipleValues` switch that needs turning on to true, and this should set the tick.

I cannot seem to find it and also I am not sure where to set it.

I have casted the column to :

```
txField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField);
```

and I still cannot find the property to set it, to true.

Any ideas ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the below code, I have added `Mult="TRUE"` this we used to use in our old codes

```
var fieldSchema = <Field Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" 
                         Name="SessionTopics" 
                         Mult="TRUE"
                         DisplayName="Session Topics"
                         Required="TRUE" 
                         Group="Limited Document Library" />;
```

Comment: Excellent, I was going the wrong way after reading that it cannot be set in xml. thanks a lot.